# How to pass array[int] to function with out var

Tags: c

How to pass array[int] to function with out declare variable

```
void foo(int *arr);
foo([1,2,3,4]);
```

Comment: it will of course allocate space for the data. No magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foo((int[]){1,2,3,4});
```

Comment: Reference for compound literals - http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5

Answer (score 1):

to be **`out`** in the C# understanding

```
    int *arr;
    foo((arr = (int[]){1,2,3,4}));
```

https://godbolt.org/z/K1ao1f